# Minimum duration in chunk size while converting to hls format using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am using `ffmpeg` to convert mp4 to .ts format. In the meta file generated I can see chunk size are random which is acceptable to me, but i need to specify minimum duration of chunk size. Like 15sec or 30sec. Currently I am using following command to convert the videos.

`ffmpeg -i ad1.mp4 -strict -2 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename 'sample-%06d.ts' -f hls sample.m3u8`

[Pastebin link for sample m3u8 file](https://pastebin.com/gXDQXw4g)

Comment: Add `-hls_time 15`

Comment: @Gyan Thanks it helped. Can you also please tell me what does `-level` flag do, i couldn;t find

Comment: That sets the codec level for those which this attribute exists. Here, it sets the H264 l[evel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels).